# Kendo DropDownList trimming in Kendo Grid's small cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, kendo-ui

I'm using a DropDownList editor in grid cells. As I have a lot of columns in my project's grid, I'm using very small cell widths. Because of that, when I click on the cell to display the DropDownList, the selected cell's text gets trimmed/replaced with "**...**" **This only happens in Chrome**, other browsers remove maybe one last digit, but that's acceptable.

Here's a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Screenshot example]

I also made a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uPeN6/13/) (please view in Chrome, other browsers are OK). Here's a code snippet for DropDownList custom cell editor:

```
function renderDropDown(container, options) {

$('<input required  name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "FilijalaKod",
        dataValueField: "FilijalaId",
        dataSource: filijale,                
        dataBound: function (e) {
            var $dropDown = $(e.sender.element),
            dataWidth = $dropDown.data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(),
            listWidth = dataWidth + 20,
            containerWidth = listWidth + 6;

            // Set widths to the new values
            $dropDown.data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(listWidth);
            //$dropDown.closest(".k-widget").width(containerWidth);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this kind of behavior in Chrome? Maybe some custom CSS rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try defining the following style:

```
#grid .k-dropdown-wrap span.k-input {
    text-overflow : clip;
}
```

Your JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/uPeN6/14/